# Time Limit Exceeded on Hackerrank

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, optimization

I successfully solved a question on Hackerrank, and it passed all test cases but I got an error Time Limit Exceeded. I'm guessing if I optimize my code it would work,but I can't think of any way to make my code more efficient.

The question is:
  A left rotation operation on an array of size n shifts each of the array's elements 1 unit to the left. For example, if 2 left rotations are performed on array [1,2,3,4,5], then the array would become [3,4,5,1,2].

Given an array of n integers and a number, d, perform d left rotations on the array. Then print the updated array as a single line of space-separated integers.

Can any one please guide me on how to make this code more efficient?

My code is:

```
vector<int> array_left_rotation(vector<int> a, int n, int k) {
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){
        a[n] = a[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            a[i] = a[i+1];
        }
        a[n-1] = a[n];
    }
    return a;
}
```

n is the number of elements in the array
k is the number of rotations to be performed

Comment: use [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)?

Comment: Please refrain asking questions about online code judge engines here. It's very  unlikely that anyone could tell you where you failed from their test cases, as these aren't disclosed usually. Even if what you tested was running at your local environment, you may have missed to test some edge cases which are applied in the online challenge. Be creative and try to find them. Additionally there's probably no value for such questions in the long term, other than cheating the online contest, and nothing is learned.

Comment: How about you just print the array from position `d` to `n` and then from `0` to `d` so you don't actually need to rotate anything?

Comment: You don't need to do the rotations, you can use maths.

Comment: With the given ranges of `d` and `n`, your method would end up copying 10,000,000,000 integers. That can take a while.

Comment: Start with `c = k%n`, then use `c` instead of `k`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to actually rotate the array for this problem. The formula `(i + k) % n` will give you the element at index `i` in an array that has been rotated `k` times to the left. Knowing this you can pass through the array once accessing each element in this manner:

```c++
int main() {
  int* arr, n, k, i;
  cin >> n >> k;
  arr = new int[n];
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    cin >> arr[i];
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    cout << arr[(i + k) % n] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performing k rotations, try performing a k-rotation:
Rotate the entire array left by k in one go. That's much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If another vector will not cause a space problem, you may just copy them with an offset:

```
//Not tested
vector<int> array_left_rotation(vector<int> a, int n, int k) {
    std::vector<int> result(n);
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){
       result[j]=a[(j+k)%n];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int a[1000000],b[1000000];
    int n,d;
    cin>>n;
    cin>>d;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for(int i=0,j;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            j=n-d;
            b[j]=a[i];
        }
        else if(i==d)
        {
            j=i-d;
            b[j]=a[i];
        }
        else 
        { 
            j=(n-d+i);
            if(j>n)
            {
                j=(i-d);
                b[j]=a[i];
            }
            else
            {
                j=(n-d+i);
                b[j]=a[i];
            }
        } 
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<b[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

This passes all the test cases. What i actually did is to move each element in array `a[i]` k times in an another array `b[i]` as there is no space constraint.